# Trying to upload images I get

Tags: support, bug, image

> Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server

Whether the image is shown in diminution on the left or not, and whether it's is JPEG or PNG.

What is up?

Comment: This is an SE-wide problem, see [mother meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382916/263383) for more information.

Comment: While I was having this same problem a few days ago, it seems to have gone away now.

Answer (score 2):

Testing from my account …

> [image]

According to [this network-wide Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382916/280545), this is a problem which has been intermittently fixed and reoccurring recently.